# SSIS. Import 500 files

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I need to import big number of files. How can I write script/C# to supply SSIS package with file names to import?

SQL 2008

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the ForEach container and set it to a File Enumerator.  You'll need a variable to contain the path to the file and you'll need to set an expression on your file connector to pick up the files as they're enumerated.